# Kentico - Display first/one value of checked values (boxes)

Tags: kentico

Not sure how to write a short but meaningful title for the question but I'd like to know if there's a way to display the first (or the second or third etc.) value through Eval or in the macro with Where Condition in the sample code below.

```
Eval ("PracticeAreas[FIRST ITEM]")
PracticeAreas = '{%CurrentDocument.PracticeAreas[FIRST ITEM]#%}'
```

PracticeAreas is an item in a Page type, and it has Multiple Choice form control.
Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple Choice form control saves values as string 'value1|value2|...'. So you just need to split this field by | character.

K#:

```
{% CurrentDocument.PracticeAreas.Split("|")[0] %}
```

C#:

```
<%# Eval("PracticeAreas").ToString().Split('|')[0] %>
```

Comment: I believe this is the better answer compared to my answer, I think I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

CurrentDocument.PracticeAreas will contain the value selected not the options.

This [blog post](http://www.imediainc.com/blog/march-2016/access-the-list-of-options-in-page-type-control) might help you get what you want.